# Keyboard preview in Winform calling a Wpf Usercontrol

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, keyboard

I have a Winform app from which I call a Wpf Usercontrol that is in fact a Viewport3D on which the Winform app draws 3D elements such as cylinders.

I need to access the keyboard from the Winform app in order to catch the ^+ and ^- keystrokes to Zoom In / Out, and the arrow keys to rotate the display.

The basic code appears below. The keyboardControl Handler is defined in Sub New. While mouseControl works well, the keyboard strokes are never received by Form1. Keyboard Preview is enabled in Form1.

Would anyone have a suggestion ?

Thanks in advance. Claude

```
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, _
                               e      As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 


        ' Create the WPF UserControl.
        '
        WpfUc        = New UserControl1
        ' ==========================

        Host.Dock =  DockStyle.Fill
        Host.Name = "Host"


        ' Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's
        ' Child property.
        '
        Host.Child = WpfUc      


        ' Add the ElementHost control to the form's
        ' collection of child controls.
        '
        Me.Controls.Add(Host)


        Visual3d            = New ModelVisual3D
        Group3d             = New Model3DGroup

     
        Visual3d.Content      = Group3d
        WpfUc.myViewport.Children.Add(Visual3d)


        DefineCamera(TheCamera, WpfUC.myViewport)
        DefineModelCylinders(Group3d)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DefineCamera(ByRef iCamera     As OrthographicCamera,          _
                             ByRef viewport    As Windows.Controls.Viewport3D)

        iCamera                   = New OrthographicCamera
        CameraController          = New SphericalCameraController(iCamera, viewport, WpfUc, WpfUc, WpfUc)
        iCamera.FarPlaneDistance  = 100
        iCamera.NearPlaneDistance = 0
        iCamera.Position          = New Point3D(0, 0, 100)
        iCamera.Width             = 15

    End Sub

    Friend Sub New(ByVal Camera          As OrthographicCamera,           _
                   ByVal viewport        As Windows.Controls.Viewport3D,  _
                   ByVal keyboardControl As UIElement,                    _
                   ByVal wheelControl    As UIElement,                    _
                   ByVal mouseControl    As UIElement)

        TheCamera                   = Camera
        viewport.Camera             = TheCamera

        iKeyboardControl            = keyboardControl
        AddHandler KeyboardControl.PreviewKeyDown,      AddressOf KeyboardControl_KeyDown

        iWheelControl               = wheelControl
        AddHandler WheelControl.PreviewMouseWheel,      AddressOf WheelControl_PreviewMouseWheel

        iMouseControl               = mouseControl
        AddHandler iMouseControl.MouseDown,             AddressOf MouseControl_MouseDown

        PositionCamera()

    End Sub

  Private Sub KeyboardControl_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                      ByVal e      As KeyEventArgs)

        Select Case e.Key
            Case Key.Up
                IncreasePhi()
            Case Key.Down
                DecreasePhi()
            Case Key.Left
                IncreaseTheta()
            Case Key.Right
                DecreaseTheta()
            Case Key.Add, Key.OemPlus
                IncreaseR()
            Case Key.Subtract, Key.OemMinus
                DecreaseR()
        End Select

        PositionCamera()
    End Sub
```

The Wpf UserControl appears below.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1"
    d:DesignWidth="477.396" d:DesignHeight="274.41"
    >
   <Grid Margin="0">
      <!-- Viewport3D is the rendering surface. -->
      <Viewport3D x:Name="myViewport" x:FieldModifier="Public" Margin="0,0,0,0">
      </Viewport3D>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after quite a bit of research and Trial and Error, I found out that 2 settings of the Wpf Usercontrol are required for the keyboard inputs to be passed along to the hosting Form:

```
    WpfUc.Focusable = True

    WpfUC.myViewport.Focusable = True
```

Easy enough, but hard to find ...